# How do I define a FactoryGirl factory that returns a Hash with stringed keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

I have this code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :gimme_a_hash, class: Hash do
    one 'the number 1'
    two 'the number 2'
  end
end
```

It returns a hash that looks like:

```
1.9.3p448 :003 > FactoryGirl.build : gimme_a_hash
 => {:one=>"the number 1", :two=>"the number 2"}
```

How do I create a factory that returns a Hash with stringified numbers as keys?

Ideally i'd like to have the following hash returned:

```
 => { "1"=>"the number 1", "2"=>"the number 2"}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any other way. But this is one way of doing it

```
  factory :gimme_a_hash, class: Hash do |f|
    f.send(1.to_s, 'the number 1')
    f.send(2.to_s, 'the number 2')

    initialize_with {attributes.stringify_keys}
  end
```

**Result:**

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > FactoryGirl.build(:gimme_a_hash)
 => {"1"=>"the number 1", "2"=>"the number 2"}
```

**Update**

By default, factory_girl initializes the object of the given class and then calls the setter to set the values. In this case, `a=Hash.new` and then `a.1 = 'the_number_1'` which is not going  to work

By saying `initialize_with {attributes}`, i am asking it to do `Hash.new({"1" => "the number 1", "2" => "the number 2"})`

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction) for more info

Comment: Could you please explain the `initialize_with` and it's block? I'd also love to understand how you came to the decision of using `f.send`.

Comment: Thank you.  I posted a follow up Q with a different requirement set if you feel like taking a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645009/factorygirl-factory-with-traits-that-returns-a-hash-with-stringed-keys

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the attributes_for method.

```
factory :user do
  age { Kernel.rand(50) + 18 }
  email 'fake@example.com'
end

FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
=> { :age => 31, :email => "fake@example.com" }

FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user).stringify_keys
=> { "age" => 31, "email" => "fake@example.com" }
```

Comment: I don't think he is looking for `attributes_for`. `attributes_for` implied you have have an Object rather than a data structure.