# FactoryGirl factory with Trait(s) that returns a Hash with stringed keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to use `FactoryGirl` to build a `Hash` that returns something like this:

```
 => {"3"=>"1", "6"=>"Word"}
```

I'm getting close but not 100% there yet...

The first factory definition i tried looked like this:

```
factory :faqtory, class: Hash do |f|
  f.ignore do
    fake_word Faker::Lorem.word
  end

  f.sequence(1.to_s) { |n| n }
  f.send(2.to_s,  fake_word.to_s.capitalize)

  initialize_with { attributes.stringify_keys }
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
1.9.3p448 :001 > FactoryGirl.build :faqtory
ArgumentError: Trait not registered: fake_word
```

After that didn't work i assumed the call to `fake_word` needed to be in a block but that makes no difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignored attributes are defined as methods that you can use from other attributes. When referring to them, you need to define the dependent attributes using a block:

```
factory :faqtory, class: Hash do |f|
  f.ignore do
    fake_word { Faker::Lorem.word }
  end

  f.sequence(1.to_s) { |n| n }
  f.send(2.to_s) { fake_word.to_s.capitalize }

  initialize_with { attributes.stringify_keys }
end
```

Defining an attribute without a block only works for literal values like `1` or `"hello"`.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, you probably want `fake_word` to use a block as well.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It's SUPER close, but unfortunately not a working solution.  Each factory object built has the same value for key `"2"`.. Same output as i pasted for @vimsha http://pastie.org/8559316 .  I am sure this has to do with "lazy attributes" ( https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes) but not sure how to implement a solution.

Comment: Ah got it! Line 3 should be: `fake_word { Faker::Lorem.word }`.  If you update the answer, i will select as correct

Comment: Yes, if you want a different word each time, you'll want a block there, too. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  factory :faqtory, class: Hash do |f|
    fake_word = Faker::Lorem.word

    f.sequence(1.to_s) { |n| n }
    f.send(2.to_s,  fake_word.to_s.capitalize)

    initialize_with { attributes.stringify_keys }
  end
```

Comment: I have tried this and it sorta works. All factory objects you build using this will have the same attributes… example: http://pastie.org/8559316  (I would expect that the `fake_word` should be changing)